# Extracting inline images coming in mail body using java Mail API

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have written two methods one for attachments and one email body content. I need to extract the images from email body. These two methods are working fine but when images are coming in email body it is should be saved in database. So it can be used later.

**For attachmnents**:-
public static List getAttachments(MimeMultipart multipart, List existingAttachments) {

```
    if (multipart != null) {
        try {
            if (existingAttachments == null) {
                existingAttachments = new ArrayList<MimeBodyPart>();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
                if (multipart.getBodyPart(i) instanceof MimeBodyPart) {
                    MimeBodyPart currentPart = (MimeBodyPart) multipart.getBodyPart(i);
                    if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(currentPart.getDisposition())) {
                        if (!existingAttachments.contains(currentPart)) {
                            existingAttachments.add(currentPart);
                            System.out.println(currentPart.getFileName());
                        }
                    } else if (currentPart.getContent() instanceof MimeMultipart) {
                        existingAttachments = getAttachments((MimeMultipart) currentPart.getContent(), existingAttachments);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailUtil.class.getName()).error(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailUtil.class.getName()).error(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return existingAttachments;
}
```

**for email Body Content**This method is extracting email body content

```
public static String getContent(MimeMultipart multipart) {
    String emailContent = null;
    if (multipart != null) {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
                if (multipart.getBodyPart(i) instanceof MimeBodyPart) {
                    MimeBodyPart currentPart = (MimeBodyPart) multipart.getBodyPart(i);
                    if (Part.INLINE.equalsIgnoreCase(currentPart.getDisposition())) {
                        LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailUtil.class.getName()).info("Content dispo is inline");
                        emailContent = (String) currentPart.getContent();
                    } else if (currentPart.getDisposition() == null && currentPart.getContentType().toLowerCase().contains("text")) {
                        LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailUtil.class.getName()).info("Content dispo is null and type is text/*");
                        try {
                           emailContent = (String) currentPart.getContent();

                        } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
                            LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailUtil.class.getName()).warn("Classcast exception caught and managed");
                            try {
                                InputStream is = currentPart.getInputStream();

                                emailContent = IOUtils.toString(is, currentPart.getEncoding());
                                Document doc=Jsoup.parse(emailContent);
                                Elements elements =doc.getElementsByTag("img");
                                System.out.println(elements);
                                int htmlCloseIndex = emailContent.indexOf("</html>");
                                emailContent = emailContent.substring(0, htmlCloseIndex);
                                emailContent+="</html>";
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailUtil.class.getName()).error("Exception rebound caught and managed, email content will not read");
                                //emailContent = "Unable to read email content";
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }else if (currentPart.getDisposition() == null && currentPart.getContentType().contains("TEXT")) {
                        LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailUtil.class.getName()).info("Content dispo is null and type is TEXT/*");
                        try {
                            emailContent = (String) currentPart.getContent();
                        } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
                            LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailUtil.class.getName()).warn("Classcast exception caught and managed");
                            try {
                                InputStream is = currentPart.getInputStream();
                                emailContent = IOUtils.toString(is, currentPart.getEncoding());

                                int htmlCloseIndex = emailContent.indexOf("</html>");
                                emailContent = emailContent.substring(0, htmlCloseIndex);
                                emailContent+="</html>";
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailUtil.class.getName()).error("Exception rebound caught and managed, email content will not read");
                                //emailContent = "Unable to read email content";
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                    else if (currentPart.getContent() instanceof MimeMultipart) {
                        emailContent = getContent((MimeMultipart) currentPart.getContent());

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailUtil.class.getName()).error(ex.getMessage());
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailUtil.class.getName()).warn("email content will not read");
           //emailContent = "Unable to read email content";
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailUtil.class.getName()).error(ex.getMessage());
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailUtil.class.getName()).warn("email content will not read");
           // emailContent = "Unable to read email content";
        } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailUtil.class.getName()).warn("Classcast exception caught and managed");
        // emailContent = "Unable to read email content";
        }
    }
    return emailContent;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you specify what it is you actually want help with?
I can think of multiple problems you could mean: how to get the bytes of an image, how to store image data in a database.

As a side note / not central to your question: catching classcastexception is bad practice in my opinion when you have an instanceof operator you can use to test if an object is part of a class.

Comment: Yes  I want to get the byte of the image and want to store in my local directory.

Answer (score 0):

Okay one starts with the `<img src="...">` tags, you already took:

```
Elements elements = doc.getElementsByTag("img");
```

An `img` tag for an embedded image looks like:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,..." ...>
```

So having the `src` attribute do:

```
String src = ...
if (src.startsWith("data:")) { // Embedded image data.
    int p = src.indexOf(';'); // Or better ";base64,"
    if (p == -1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    String mimeType = src.substring(5, p);
    String base64Data = src.substring(p + 1 + 6 + 1); // ";base64,"
    byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Data);
    String file = "test." + mimeType.replaceFirst("^.*/(.*)$", "$1");
    Path path = Paths.get(file);
    Files.write(path, data);
}
```

Comment: I am not getting like this<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,..." ...>...  for me I am extracting emails body and getting <img> tag like this <img width="300" height="210" id="Picture_x0020_1" src="cid:image001.png@01D59592.525BA800">

Comment: That cid: protocol shows the alternative of having the image as attachment, which is simpler. https://blog.mailtrap.io/embedding-images-in-html-email-have-the-rules-changed/ - simple get the attachment with that cid.